# Host sites for react web sites

Tags: reactjs

How to host a site react js? Which hosting site that offers this service? I am just starting to learn to react and I want a lot of information, any help is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Heroku. You can create a free account and watch a tutorial or two on how to deploy a webpage.

As for React, you can compile your project with (npm run build) into a build folder, which is the minimized code that you can deploy onto the server.

Check out this tutorial: https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08

(Sorry for the bad formatting. on a phone!)

Comment: Please add relevant parts from your link here.

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean exactly?